# Launching an external android app in C#/Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

So i've been stuck on this problem for literally days. I have integrated Unity with Eclipse IDE and i can build and deploy projects perfectly. However, im trying to start an a basic Intent on the java side and trigger it on the Unity/C# side.

Here's my code for the Java side:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity;

public class AppLauncher extends UnityPlayerNativeActivity 
{

    public  Intent myIntent;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Assuming that we want to launch the browser to browse a website
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        myIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {       
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
}
```

Here's the error im getting thrown by logcat when the C# trigger is hit:

And here's my code for the C# side of if it:

```
if(s[0].Equals("Spr"))
{
    print("Launched");
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    jo.Call("Trigger");
}
```

Here's the error im getting thrown by logcat when the C# trigger is hit:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='Trigger' signature='()V' in class Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerNativeActivity;
```

I've tried screwing around by passong a custom signature along with the Trigger method name in the C# script, ive tried extending the standard UnityPlayerActivity, etc... I've tried hours worth of stuff and i Cannot seem to solve tis problem.

Any help is greatly accepted!

Comment: Anyone? Really need help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your activity is created? Do you really need to extend the activity? I'd try something like this:

Java:

```
package my.package;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AppLauncher 
{
    public static void Trigger()
    {     
        //Assuming that we want to launch the browser to browse a website
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent myIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);  
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

C#:

```
AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("my.package.AppLauncher");
jo.CallStatic("Trigger");
```

Comment: How would i pass variables through to the method? I try, (method, "mystring") but the java engine thinks the second var is used for the signature of the method..